# CSS/JQUERY make div scrollable without showing scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

is there any way to make a div scrollable with overflow-y:hidden; and overflow-x:hidden?

i'm trying without success, maybe i need some js or jquery script?

i mean, i would like to make div scroll on y axes without showing scrollbar on right side( as it is now).

itryed:

```
.get-list{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:444;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  bottom:0;
  clear:both !important;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:11%;

  margin:0 auto;
  background:#fff;
  max-height:800px;
  overflow-y:no-display;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  display: block;
 }
```

thanks

EDIT

```
.log-widget-list{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:444;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  width:99%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#fff;
  height:800px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.log-widget-list .scroller{
  overflow: scroll; 
  height:800px;
  width:100%;
}
```

it shows right scrollbar anyway

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I think OP has tried `overflow-y: hidden` and `overflow-x: hidden`, but that did not work.

Comment: @Blender: Not quite - that's why I asked. (see edit)

Comment: If there is no scrollbar, how is it supposed to scroll? Automatically?

Comment: Yes you can by using jQuery.scrollLeft and jQuery.scrollTop.

Comment: some trick to hide scroll bar i mean

Comment: i'm on boostrap don't want to use more plugins :(

Comment: @Ispuk You can use scrollTo(xpos,ypos);

Comment: examples? i mean $('get-list').scrollTo(); i tink is not ok :P

Comment: need to bind mouse wheel event? :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's create a div with a width of 200px: (note the `overflow:hidden`)

```
#sidebar{
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #000;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Inside that div we will create the 'scrollable' div. See:

```
#sidebar #scroller{
    width: 215px;
    height: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: scroll; 
}​
```

Altough we give it `overflow:scroll`, the scrollbar isn't visible. This is because this div has a total width of 215px which will make the scrollbar disappear outside the div.

Also see: http://jsfiddle.net/TBsN8/

Comment: You should copy the code over to this answer and explain how/why it works.

Comment: true. will certainly get my `+1` after that :)

Comment: @Sebass van Boxel i edited code , i think % width still not working

Comment: man it's clear but it doesn't works for me :( does it's a problem position:absolute or %width? :P check my question is updated

Comment: Delete position:absolute and display: none and add padding-right:15px; to .log-widget-list .scroller{
see: http://jsfiddle.net/TBsN8/1/

Comment: fixed ;) thx never seen this css trick really good trick man!

Comment: @Sebass van Boxel: Try your demo in Chrome/Safari: highlight/select a line and drag your mouse to the right and you'll see the scrollbar. Or use a textarea instead of the inner div and then fill it with some text. Then use the keyboard keys `Page Up` and `Page Down`.

Answer (score 0):

fixed as shown thanks to Sebass van Boxel

```
.log-widget-list{
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
  width:98% !important;
  top:11%;
  max-height:500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom:0 !important;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto !important;
 }

.log-widget-list .scroller{
  overflow: scroll; 
  max-height:500px;
  padding-bottom:3%;
  width:104% !important;
}
```